# Typecasting pointers

Tags: c, typecasting-operator

I have a **variable**

```
UInt32 PageAddr = 0x80000000;
```

and a **function**

```
UInt8 Blank_Check(const UInt8 *Address)
```

I am calling the **function** after typecasting variable.

```
Blank_Check((UInt8 *)&PageAddr);
```

What will be the **value** that will be passed to the blank check. I tried to analyze but I am unable to understand how it works?

Comment: The address-of operator `&` when used as in your function call will take the address of the variable `PageAddr`, i.e. not its value `0x8000000`.

Comment: You probably want to call it as `Blank_Check((const UInt8 *)PageAddr);`

Comment: yes, like @anishsane said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short version: remove the `&` character.*

**Longer version:**

It will be exactly the same pointer value. The type is only there to help the C compiler know how to index and dereference the pointer.

To clarify the difference between value and pointer, try:

```
UInt32 PageAddr = 0x80000000;
printf("%d,   %p\n", PageAddr, &PageAddr);
```

By the name of variable, I guess you really want to do something like:

```
Uint32* PageAddr = 0x80000000;   /* as a pointer */

Blank_Check((UInt8 *)PageAddr);  /* cast pointer to another kind of pointer */
```

Or if you want to keep the pointer represented as an integer (works on almost all platforms, but is not 100% portable), like this:

```
Uint32 PageAddr = 0x80000000;   /* as an integer */

Blank_Check((UInt8 *)PageAddr); /* cast integer to pointer */
```

Comment: No, the pointer (= address) to where 0x80000000 is stored, will be passed.

Answer (score 1):

The passed value is the address where the variable `PageAddr` has been put in memory by the compiler. That's the passed **value**.

Actually, C is a pass-by-value only language. When you pas a variable, the variable's value is passed. When you pass a pointer, like `&PageAddr` the address of `PageAddr` becomes the value that is passed.

Later, in the called function, you can use the address-value to look or changed what's stored in that address.

This is in contrast to languages that allow passing also by reference, like C++ or Java, where a reference to the value is passed, in which case anything you do to or with the reference, is actually done to the original variable.